# Link breaks when visitors use different urls to same page

Tags: html, url, anchor, href, relative-path

I am building a website. The files are:

```
/index.php
/pic.jpg
/dir/index.php
/dir/pic.jpg
```

people can visit my site's `dir/index.php` page using different urls:

```
1. site.com/dir
2. site.com/dir/ 
3. site.com/dir/index.php
```

I have a link in `/dir/index.php`, which I want to relativly link to `/dir/pic.jpg` :

```
<a target="_blank" href="pic.jpg">
```

**The problem is**: people using url 1 get `/pic.jpg` , and others using url 2 or 3 get `/dir/pic.jpg`

How can I write a relative `<a>` link in `/dir/index.php` that links to `/dir/pic.jpg` whatever url visitors use?

I want to make folder `dir` portable (I may change `dir`'s name, or copy `dir` folder to another site so it may have different path), so hard code `href="/dir/pic.jpg"` isn't a good solution.

Comment: so when you link `<a target="_blank" href="pic.jpg">` you get the picture in `/dir/pic.jpg` are you asking how to link to `/pic.jpg` ? (outside of `dir`)

Comment: Your 3 proposed urls should be equivalent (in a standard server installation). Then what makes the things different? In your case, urls like `site.com` should be different than `site.com/dir`. Not clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `../` to go back a directory. Thus, if you're in the `dir` folder and you want to go out of this folder into its parent directory you can use:

```
<a target="_blank" href="../pic.jpg">Link</a>
```

Or you can simply just use your site's URL (however this isn't as robust):

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com/pic.jpg">Link</a>
```